# How many open files for each process running for a specific user in Linux

Tags: linux, lsof

Running Apache and Jboss on Linux, sometimes my server halts unexpectedly saying that the problem was Too Many Open Files.

I know that we might set a higher limit for *nproc* and *nofile* at */etc/security/limits.conf* to fix the open files problem, but I am trying to get better output, such as using *watch* to monitor them in real-time.

With this command line I can see how many open files per PID:

```
lsof -u apache | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Output (Column 1 is # of open files for the user apache):

```
1     PID
1335  13880
1389  13897
1392  13882
```

If I could just add the watch command it would be enough, but the code below isn't working:

```
watch lsof -u apache | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Answer (score 6):

You should put the command insides quotes like this:

```
watch 'lsof -u apache | awk '\''{print $2}'\'' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n'
```

or you can put the command into a shell script like test.sh and then use watch.

```
chmod +x test.sh
watch ./test.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

This command will tell you how many files Apache has opened:

```
ps -A x |grep apache | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I '{}' ls /proc/{}/fd  | wc -l
```

You may have to run it as root in order to access the process fd directory. This sounds like you've got a web application which isn't closing its file descriptors. I would focus my efforts on that area.